# sending a specific xml file through action in js

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to send home.xml from htdocs to server

like

```
<form action="server.com:3000" fileToSend="home.xml">
```

is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

To recieve the file on the server you are going to have to write some server side code.  On the half of the client code you can add a tag like the following:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/UploadServlet?">
   <input type="file" name="fileToSend" id="fileToSend" />
 </form>
```

This will get the file sent to the server, receiving and storing it is now up to the Server-Side code (UploadServlet in this example).

Comment: i am sending the file to UPS SERVER so i have no control on writing the code on that side